# How do I decompile a specific kernel function?

Tags: linux-kernel, decompiler

For example ,kernen function `system_call` decompiles to:

```
push %eax
...
call * 0xc03094c0(,%eax,,4)
```

How's this done in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be as simple as this:

Compile your kernel with debugging symbols, or if you're using your distro's version, grab its debug package.  Then run `gdb vmlinux` and type `disas <function name>` if you want to look at a C function.  Except that `system_call` isn't a C function, so GDB won't look it up the same way.  But you can still disassemble:

```
(gdb) info addr system_call
Symbol "system_call" is at 0xc0403964 in a file compiled without debugging.
(gdb) x/4i 0xc0403964
   0xc0403964:  push   %eax
   0xc0403965:  cld    
   0xc0403966:  push   %fs
   0xc0403968:  push   %es
```

Comment: What is `system_call` if it's not a C function?

Comment: @assem: It's just a linker symbol that resolves to the address of some assembly code.  You can see its definition [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37.5/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L496).

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't really need to decompile anything since its linux. You can just look at the source. A good source browser is [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/). Join the kernel mailing list if you need help, they are very nice people.